# Git multiple repository synchronisation

Tags: git, synchronization, repository, version

I have two git-based repository, one of them depends someway on another. I'm a little worried about syncronisity between them. I can maintain some stable, always buildable state on top of repository history. Let say, master branch. But it's not enough.

If I wish checkout previous state, I should be sure, that both repositories reverted to correct state, and this state of repositories corresponds each other.

For example: I have A and B repository. A1 is first commit in A repository.
I have history like:

1. A1 - A2 - A3 - A4
2. B1 - B2 - B3

And B3 - A4, B3 - A3 pairs are working. But B3 don't work with A2. And If I revert A repository to the point A2, I must revert to B2 too.

Sorry, if my explanation is a little complicated.

I know about git-subtree and submodules, but the former merges history, and I dislike the latter for many reasons.

So, I'm looking for another solution. Only thing I have come now is using git-hooks, to add information about top commits of each repo, to each commit message. But it involves a lot of manual work, every time, I checkout previous state of any repository. Plus it will depend on repository physical location.

Answer (score 2):

Did you heard of git slave? http://gitslave.sourceforge.net/. It could be another solution for you

Comment: Thanks! It looks interesting at first glance. As I understand, reading tutorial, it will consolidate commit information in superproject log. I'll play with it little later.